# What do I need to convert my Angular2 component to ES6 syntax?

Tags: import, ecmascript-6, angular, iife

#### index.js

Here is my entry point

```
import * as stylesheet from '../assets/styles/app.scss';

import jQuery from '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery';
import $ from '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery';

import {bootstrap}    from './boot'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

#### app.component.js

This works

```
(function (app) {
    app.AppComponent = ng.core
        .Component({
            selector: 'my-app',
            template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
            }
        });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

#### Question

I tried to use answer from [How do I write angular2 without decorator syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356562/802365) without success.

- How do I get rid of the `IIFE` and use `ES6` syntax?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to use ES6 with or without the `@Class` decorator support? If it's the latter, you need to enable decorator support via transpiler settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Babel and use the following plugins: `'angular2-annotations', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-flow-strip-types'` there is no need to convert the syntax.

You can check it also in a [working example](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-es6-starter).

Answer (score 2):

Untested!

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>
        My First Angular 2 App
    </h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor () {

  }
}
```

Perhaps you got a little confused by thinking you needed the `app` variable?

Just to be clear you don't need to reference `app`, you just need to import `AppComponent` (as you already have)